# How can I draw this figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

I found this picture in a book (Ultrafiltration by M. Cheryan). I need to draw something like this. Is it possible using Latex or do I need a plot software?

Comment: What do you need the diagram for? Could you not just put the figure as it is in your report or whatever document you are writing and reference it to that book? Latex can create that plot but you will need to put a bit of effort into doing it, it is a little complicated.

Comment: If you have the data to be plotted, then you can use pgfplots (and possibly standalone) to display it.

Comment: You'd use tikz for this, e.g. for plotting, which you can include in Latex code. To learn about it, start with the minimal introduction and look for specific details in the big manual here: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf . // The tikz-gallery provides some examples, like this one: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/line-plot-example/ . // Also search this site, e.g.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=line+plot . // Also have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-datavisualization .